# Spring: Accessing validation group in binding result?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

Is this possible?

For example I have a controller method like the follows with the binding result.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String employee(@ModelAttribute @Validated(BasicDetails.class) Employee employee, BindingResult binding {
              if(binding.hasErrors()){
              return "failView";
                }

            return "successView";
            }
```

My employee class below(I have omitted a lot of unnecessary details). The name field is part of the BasicDetails groups ,when this field fails validation(when it is empty) it appears in the errors property of binding result but I can't see any information on the group. Does the group ever get passed to binding results? Is there any nice way to access the group information in my above controller method?

```
public class Employee{

   @Size(min=1,groups=BasicDetails.class)
   public String name;

  public interface BasicDetails{}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm doubt that it's possible. And why do you need it at all? I can't imagine an use-case for that.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin there could be lots of use cases if you have inheritance and some values get inherited from the father to children which are getting used in different objects